# Unable to send multiple values to another page using php session variable

Tags: php

Am trying to make a mini shopping cart where the user can buy goods.
Everything's working fine but when I check out, only the second product in the cart gets loaded in the check out option and not the first product, this means if the cart has only 1 product, it works well and good, but when added second product, it takes the second product and not the first one. Please correct me where am making mistake.

Here's the code that I have tried at my level best.

```
<?php
// Session Start
session_start();
include 'storescripts/dbconnect.php';

?>
<?php
// Add To The Cart
if (isset($_POST['pid'])) {
    $id = $_POST['pid'];
    $wasFound = false;
    $i = 0;
    if (!isset($_SESSION["cart_array"]) || count($_SESSION["cart_array"]) < 1) {
        $_SESSION["cart_array"] = array(
                                    0 => array(
                                        "item_id" => $id, "quantity" => 1
                                        )
                                    );
    } else {
        foreach ($_SESSION["cart_array"] as $each_item) {
            $i++;
            while (list($key, $value) = each($each_item)) {
                if ($key == "item_id" && $value == $id) {
                    array_splice($_SESSION["cart_array"], $i - 1, 1, array(array("item_id" => $id, "quantity" => $each_item['quantity'] + 1)));
                    $wasFound = true;
                }
            }
        }
        if ($wasFound == false) {
            array_push($_SESSION["cart_array"], array("item_id" => $id, "quantity" => 1));
        }
    }
    header("Location: cart.php");
    exit();
}
?>
<?php
// Empty The Cart
if (isset($_GET['cmd']) && $_GET['cmd'] == "emptycart") {
    unset($_SESSION["cart_array"]);
}
?>
<?php
// Adjust The Item Quantity
if (isset($_POST['itemToAdjust']) && $_POST['itemToAdjust'] != "") {
    $itemToAdjust = $_POST['itemToAdjust'];
    $itemQuantity = $_POST['itemQuantity'];
    $itemQuantity = preg_replace('#[^0-9]#i', '', $itemQuantity);
    if ($itemQuantity >= 100) {
        $itemQuantity = 99;
    }

    if ($itemQuantity < 1) {
        $itemQuantity = 1;
    }
    $i = 0;
    foreach ($_SESSION["cart_array"] as $each_item) {
        $i++;
        while (list($key, $value) = each($each_item)) {
            if ($key == "item_id" && $value == $itemToAdjust) {
                array_splice($_SESSION["cart_array"], $i - 1, 1, array(array("item_id" => $itemToAdjust, "quantity" => $itemQuantity)));
            }
        }
    }
}

?>
<?php
// Remove Item If User Choose To
if (isset($_POST['idToRemove']) && $_POST['idToRemove'] != "") {
    $keyToRemove = $_POST['idToRemove'];
    if (count($_SESSION["cart_array"]) <= 1) {
        unset($_SESSION["cart_array"]);
    } else {
        unset($_SESSION["cart_array"]["$keyToRemove"]);
        sort($_SESSION["cart_array"]);
    }
}
?>
<?php
// Render The Cart For The User To View
if (!isset($_SESSION['product_name'])) {
    $_SESSION['product_name'] = array();
}
if (!isset($_SESSION['price'])) {
    $_SESSION['price'] = array();
}
include 'moneyFormat.php';
$cartOutput = "";
$cartTotal = "";
$cartTotalPrice = "";
$cartTotalPriceString = "";

if (!isset($_SESSION["cart_array"]) || count($_SESSION["cart_array"]) < 1) {
    $cartOutput = "<h2 align='center'>Your Shopping Cart Is Empty.</h2>";
} else {
    $i = 0;
    foreach ($_SESSION["cart_array"] as $each_item) {
        $item_id = $each_item['item_id'];
        $sql = "SELECT *
                    FROM products
                        WHERE id='".$item_id."'
                    LIMIT 1";
        $res = mysqli_query($con, $sql);

        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res)) {
            $productName = $row['product_name'];
            //$_SESSION["product_name"] = $productName;
            $price = $row['price'];
            $details = $row['details'];
        }

        $priceTotal = $price * $each_item['quantity'];
        $cartTotal += $priceTotal;

        //echo $_SESSION["product_name"] . "<br />";
        for ($i=0; $i < count($_SESSION["product_name"]); $i++) { 
            echo $_SESSION["product_name"]."<br />";
        }
        /*if (count($_SESSION["product_name"]) > 0) {
            echo $_SESSION["product_name"] . "<br />";
        }*/

        //setlocale(LC_MONETARY, "en_IN");
        $priceTotal = money_format("%10.2n", $priceTotal);
        $price = money_format("%10.2n", $price);

        $cartOutput .= '<tr>';
        $cartOutput .= '<td><a href="product.php?id='.$item_id.'">'.$productName.'</a><br />
                        <img src="inventory_images/'.$item_id.'.jpg" alt='.$productName.' width="82" height="70" border="1">
                        </td>';
        $cartOutput .= '<td>'.$details.'</td>';
        $cartOutput .= '<td style="text-align: center;"> '.$price.'</td>';
        $cartOutput .= '<td style="text-align: center;">
                            <form action="cart.php" method="POST">
                            <input type="text" name="itemQuantity" size="1" maxlenght="2" value="'.$each_item['quantity'].'"/>
                            <input type="submit" name="btnAdjustQuantity'.$item_id.'" value="Change" />
                            <input type="hidden" name="itemToAdjust" value="'.$item_id.'" />
                            </form>
                        </td>';
        //$cartOutput .= '<td style="text-align: center;">'.$each_item['quantity'].'</td>';
        $cartOutput .= '<td style="text-align: center;"> '.$priceTotal.'</td>';
        $cartOutput .= '<td style="text-align: center;">
                            <form action="cart.php" method="POST">
                            <input type="submit" name="btnDeleteQuantity'.$item_id.'" value="Remove" />
                            <input type="hidden" name="idToRemove" value="'.$i.'" />
                            </form>
                        </td>';
        $cartOutput .= '</tr>';
        $i++;
    }
    $cartTotalPrice = money_format("%10.2n", $cartTotal);
    $cartTotalPriceString = "<div align='right' style='font-size: 19px; margin-top: 15px;'>Cart Total: ". $cartTotalPrice . "</div>";

}
?>
<?php
$totalItems = 0;
$checkOut = "";
$quantity = 0;

if (!isset($_SESSION["cart_array"]) || count($_SESSION["cart_array"]) < 1) {
    $cartOutput = "<h2 align='center'>Your Shopping Cart Is Empty.</h2>";
} else {
    foreach ($_SESSION["cart_array"] as $each_item) {
        while (list($key, $value) = each($each_item)) {
            if ($key == 'quantity' && $each_item['quantity'] > 0) {
                $totalItems += $value;
                $quantity = $totalItems;
            }
        }
    }
}

if ($totalItems > 0) {
    $checkOut = '<a href="storescripts/render_cart.php?checkout=YES&Product='.$productName.'&Quantity='.$quantity.'&Price='.$cartTotalPrice.'">';
    $checkOut .= '<input type="submit" value="Check Out" name="checkOut" style="float: right;"/>';
    $checkOut .= '</a>';
}
?>
```

Thanks.

Comment: You should be keying your cart array by the item id. e.g. `$_SESSION['cart'][$item_id] = $quantity`. This makes it trivial to find/manipulate any particular item. Your array will require you to search the whole array anytime you want to update something.

Comment: so what am I suppose to do ? go with what you said, or need to do more research on my part ?

Comment: probably, yes. that whole foreach() loop is so totally useless due to poor array design. with the proper keying, updating an item is literally just `$_SESSIOn['cart'][$item_id]++`, replacing that ENTIRE foreach loop.

Comment: Ok. Before leaving, let me tell that am a newbie to PHP and I don't know that much. You can say that am still learning. So can you please tell which foreach loop you are pointing to and where should I paste your code ?

Comment: all of the foreach(while(if(array_splice))) ones.

Comment: You should design your array like this: `$_SESSION['cart']['item_id'] = 'quantity'` So you can easily check for existing items: `if(isset($_SESSION['cart'][$id]))` and so on. To increase the quantity use the code Marc posted above.

Comment: Also worth adding - if that is 1 complete file you posted, you don't need all the `<?php ?>` throughout your document. Just have one openening php tag `<?php` at the start. Leave the closing tag from the end as it's not really necessary. You can always use a code comment after each section if you like, usually helps remind me where certain sections of code are.